# Accessing an object that implements SelectMethod for ObjectDataSource (ASP.NET)

Tags: asp.net, objectdatasource

Is it possible to access an object that is used by ObjectDataSource to retrieve records? For example,

```
<asp:ObjectDataSource ID="MyDS" runat="server" 
    SelectMethod="getUsers" 
    TypeName="DataSources.UserDS"
    SelectCountMethod = "getUserNum"/>... </asp:ObjectDataSource>
```

`UserDS` class has `getUsers` that returns `DataTable` and `getUserNum`  that returns `int`, this part works as it's supposed. But I wonder if can access the instance of `UserDS` somehow (not underlying `DataTable`)?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

The object instance is available in the ODS created event.

```
protected void ObjectDataSource1_ObjectCreated(object sender, ObjectDataSourceEventArgs e)
{
   object objectInstance = e.ObjectInstance;
}
```